# POST Beeps questions for a new build

Tags: boot, graphics-card, motherboard, post

I've read many links about the different types of beep that a MoBo will make depending on the problem, however my current issue doesn't seem to be answered anywhere.

I have a MSI 990FXA Gaming AMD 990FX which uses the UEFI Bios I believe. Without the GFX card plugged in it beeps like a normal POST would. If I plug the GFX card in (tried all available PCIe slots, checked it's seated properly and powered fully) I get 5 short beeps but like I say without it it sounds okay.

Despite the beeps, it boots and loads windows. On a side note my PSU is making slight crackling sound which obviously doesn't sound good, so do you think a lack of proper power going to the CPU ATX connector could be causing my troubles?

Any info is appreciated :)

EDIT:

List of hardware:

- AMD Piledriver FX-8 Eight Core 8370 Black Edition 4.00GHz (Socket
  AM3+) Processor
- MSI 990FXA Gaming AMD 990FX (Socket AM3+) DDR3 ATX
  Motherboard
- Corsair Hydro H80i GT
- Corsair Vengeance RED 16GB (2x8GB) DDR3 PC3-12800C10 1600Mhz Dual Channel Kit (actually using 3 sticks not 2)
- nVidia GeForce GTX 560 (testing purposes)
- Year old 750w PSU, which is probably knackered

Comment: Without knowing anything else about the hardware we can only speculate be specific that way we can solve your problem or at least provide specific possible solutions

Comment: @Ramhound updating now

Comment: If you PSU is making electrical/crackling noises then it's failing, try another known-good PSU.

Comment: Will do, think i'll get a decent Corsair one :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to everything I can find for AMI BIOS, 5 short beeps indicates a processor failure. If the PSU is crackling (a very bad thing, BTW), it is possible that the added power drain by the graphics card is preventing the CPU from getting full power, thereby causing the BIOS beep code.

Comment: That's exactly what i'm thinking. When i heard the crackling i turned it off right away. It's not my first build so most things aren't new to me but just needed some other opinions. I think i'll buy a corsair modular PSU and hope that the lack of power is the problem. The current PSU is a 750w which is plenty but it sounds faulty

Comment: What's the make and model of the PSU? I've seen off-brand PSUs that claim wattages that bear no resemblance to what they can actually do.

Comment: http://www.ebuyer.com/255454-cit-gold-750w-fully-wired-efficient-power-supply-psucit750ugold - this is it, i bought it a year ago and havent used it much, so i reckon this is the issue

Comment: Was a PSU issue that wasn't getting power around the board properly